# Component "AppComponent" has no route config, router is undefined to navigate

Tags: angular

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core'; 
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';    
import { RouteConfig } from 'angular2/router';   
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';    
import { LandingComponent } from './landing.component';     

@RouteConfig([    
    {path: '/landing', name: 'Landing', component: LandingComponent},   
    {path: '/*other', name: 'Other', redirectTo: ['Landing']}     
]);       

@Component({     
    selector: 'cwf',    
    templateUrl: 'app/template/index.template.html',   
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]     
})    

export class AppComponent {    

    constructor(private _router:Router){

    }     

    browserObject = BrowserDetect;    
    navigator =  navigator.javaEnabled() ? "enabled" : "disabled";  
    listBrowser = BrowserDetect.supportedBrowser;    

    ngOnInit(){    
        let timer = Observable.timer(2000);  
        timer.subscribe(this.navigate);     
    };    

    navigate = () => {  
        this._router.navigate(['Landing']);  
    };      

}
```

Comment: I want to navigate the page on timeout.
    
    I have included <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script> in HTML 
    I have included import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router'
    bootstrap(AppComponent,[ROUTER_PROVIDERS]); in boot.ts
    
    Still I am getting this kind of error.. Please tell me what is the problem.

Comment: You can edit your question and add additional information there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `;` at the end of

```
@RouteConfig([    
    {path: '/landing', name: 'Landing', component: LandingComponent},   
    {path: '/*other', name: 'Other', redirectTo: ['Landing']}     
]);
```

Comment: If this solvers your problem, can you please accept the answer (white check mark below the up/down-vote buttons) to indicate this question is answered. Thanks.

Comment: I have landing page like this... import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'landing',
 templateUrl: 'app/template/landing.template.html'
});

export class LandingComponent {
 
}  // I am getting No Directive annotation found on LandingComponent.. Can you please tell me the reason

Comment: You again have a `;` at the end of `@Component(...); /* <<<=== */ export class LandingComponent {  }`. There must be no `;` between decorator and the class they are decorating