# No Directive annotation found on LandingComponent

Tags: angular

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core'; 

import { Router } from 'angular2/router';    

import { RouteConfig } from 'angular2/router';   

import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';   

import { LandingComponent } from './landing.component';     

@RouteConfig([    

  {path: '/landing', name: 'Landing', component: LandingComponent}, 

  {path: '/*other', name: 'Other', redirectTo: ['Landing']}    

])         

@Component({     

  selector: 'cwf',    

  templateUrl: 'app/template/index.template.html',  

  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]     

})    

export class AppComponent {    

  constructor(private _router:Router){

  }     

  browserObject = BrowserDetect;

  navigator =  navigator.javaEnabled() ? "enabled" : "disabled";  

  listBrowser = BrowserDetect.supportedBrowser;    

  ngOnInit(){    

    let timer = Observable.timer(2000); 

    timer.subscribe(this.navigate);   

  };    

  navigate = () => {  

    this._router.navigate(['Landing']);  

  };      

}

// Landing...    

import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({

  selector: 'landing',

  templateUrl: 'app/template/landing.template.html'

});

export class LandingComponent {


}
```

Comment: Why I am getting "No Directive annotation found on LandingComponent" on setTimeout navigation.. Please suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a redundant `;` at the end of `@Component(...); /* <<<=== */ export class LandingComponent { }`. There must be no `;` between decorator and the class they are decorating.

As also answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38454820/217408

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's because you have `;` in your code right after the `@Component` decorator for the `LandingComponent` class:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'landing',
  templateUrl: 'app/template/landing.template.html'
}); // <-----
export class LandingComponent {

}
```

Removing it should fix your problem...